# to load server.p12 file into volume mounts on a kubernetes deployment using secret

Tags: kubernetes-secrets

I have a use case to load a file ( server.p12 ) into kubernetes deployment using secret. My file structure

```
poc
[]templates
  [] certificate-secret
[]server.p12
```

The secret i have been trying is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: certificates-secret-p12
type: Opaque
data:
  {{ (.Files.Get "server.p12") }}
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. I get the following error

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid leading UTF-8 octet
```

Can anyone please help me here .

Answer (score 0):

The secret should be updated in the below manner

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: certificates-secret-p12
type: Opaque
data:
  server.p12: {{ (.Files.Get "server.p12") | b64enc  }}
```